# Phonegap 2.6 insertId and rowsAffected is always undefined. Why?

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova

Recently I upgraded my phonegap app from 1.5 to 2.6

I am using local storage database.

I found that, **insertId** and **rowsAffected** always **returns null**.
This was working fine with 1.5

*Is this a bug with phonegap's 2.6 release or anything else?*

I can get **MAX(Id)** by executing another **SELECT query**.

But this is not the desired way.

How to resolve this?

Thanks